# onChildClickListener not working in Expandable List View

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am creating an application, which has an expandable list view I am able to get the expandable list view, but my child click is not working. I am trying to display a toast message on clicking a child in expandable list view. Please help me and let me know what mistake am I doing. Thanks in advance.

```
    My Activity code:

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleCursorTreeAdapter;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;


    public class AdminActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Toolbar toolbar;
        ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
        List<String> titleText;
        SQLiteDataBaseAdapter db;

        HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

        ExpandableListView login, android, ios, testing, java, dotNet, os, hr, others;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);

            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appBar);
            toolbar.setTitle(" Admin Screen");
            toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            login = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewLogin);

            titleText = new ArrayList<>();
            titleText.add("User Id Authentication");
            titleText.add("Android Posts Authentication");
            titleText.add("iOS Posts Authentication");
            titleText.add("Testing Posts Authentication");
            titleText.add("Java Posts Authentication");
            titleText.add("Dot Net Posts Authentication");
            titleText.add("OS Posts Authentication");
            titleText.add("HR Posts Authentication");
            titleText.add("Others Posts Authentication");






            SQLiteDataBaseAdapter db = new SQLiteDataBaseAdapter(this);
            List<String> childDataLogin =  db.getLoginList();
            List<String> childDataAndroid =  db.getAndroidList();
            List<String> childDataIos =  db.getIosList();
            List<String> childDataTesting =  db.getTestingList();
            List<String> childDataJava =  db.getJavaList();
            List<String> childDataDotNet =  db.getDotNetList();
            List<String> childDataOs =  db.getOSList();
            List<String> childDataHr =  db.getHRList();
            List<String> childDataOthers =  db.getOthersList();

            listDataChild = new HashMap<>();
            listDataChild.put(titleText.get(0), childDataLogin); // Header, Child data
            listDataChild.put(titleText.get(1), childDataAndroid);
            listDataChild.put(titleText.get(2), childDataIos);
            listDataChild.put(titleText.get(3), childDataTesting);
            listDataChild.put(titleText.get(4), childDataJava);
            listDataChild.put(titleText.get(5), childDataDotNet);
            listDataChild.put(titleText.get(6), childDataOs);
            listDataChild.put(titleText.get(7), childDataHr);
            listDataChild.put(titleText.get(8), childDataOthers);



            listAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(this, titleText, listDataChild);
            login.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            // Listview on child click listener
            login.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                           titleText.get(groupPosition)
                                    + " : "
                                    + listDataChild.get(
                                    titleText.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                    childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    return true;
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_admin, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }



    }

Layout of child:



 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="?                                                                               android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

    </LinearLayout>

Adapter Code:



     public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
            private Context _context;
            private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
            // child data in format of header title, child title
            private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

            public MyExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String>            listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
                this._context = context;
                this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
                this._listDataChild = listChildData;
            }

            @Override
            public int getGroupCount() {
                return this._listDataHeader.size();
            }

            @Override
            public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
                return     this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                        .size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
                return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
            }

            @Override
            public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
                return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                        .get(childPosititon);
            }

            @Override
            public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
                return groupPosition;
            }

            @Override
            public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return childPosition;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasStableIds() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                                     View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


                String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
                }

                TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.expandableListHeader);
                lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

                return convertView;
            }

            @Override
            public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                                     boolean isLastChild, View convertView,    ViewGroup parent) {

                final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition,   childPosition);

                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                }

                TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

                txtListChild.setText(childText);
                return convertView;

            }

            @Override
            public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: post the layout of the child list item

Comment: @NoName added please check.

Comment: @Kartheek added please check

Comment: Can you provide ExpandableListAdapter code.

Answer (score 1):

Return true in the method of `isChildSelectable` 
Replace

```
  @Override
   public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
       return false;
   }
```

with

```
  @Override
  public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
       return true;
  }
```