# Android buttons inside Listview item click not working

Tags: android, listview, scroll, click

My Application main page contains a listview and the each item is a container having height 80 % of the screen and it contains many buttons and image views. When I scroll the list view and click on the icons its not accepting the click for the first time. How Can I get an ios like click response?

this is the code in getView() of my adapter

```
 pollChoice1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (message.getAnswered()) {
                if (message.getScope().equals("private") && (message.getResponseCount() < 1) && message.getVisibility().equals("public")) {
                    showAlert("Not enough people have responded to display answers");
                } else {
                    showAlert("You have already answered this poll");
                }
            } else {
                message.setAnswered(true);
                if ((message.getScope().equals("private") && message.getResponseCount() > 0) || message.getScope().equals("domain")) {
                    message.setOption1Count(message.getOption1Count() + 1);
                    message.setResponseCount(message.getResponseCount() + 1);
                }

                message.setAnswer("" + 0);

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        UpdateMessageTask updateMessageTask = new UpdateMessageTask(message);
                        updateMessageTask.execute();
                    }
                });


                PollReply pollReply = new PollReply(message);
                pollReply.execute();
            }

        }
    });

    pollChoice2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (message.getAnswered()) {
                if (message.getScope().equals("private") && (message.getResponseCount() < 1) && message.getVisibility().equals("public")) {
                    showAlert("Not enough people have responded to display answers");
                } else {
                    showAlert("You have already answered this poll");
                }
            } else {
                message.setAnswered(true);
                message.setAnswer("" + 1);
                if ((message.getScope().equals("private") && message.getResponseCount() > 0) || message.getScope().equals("domain")) {
                    message.setOption2Count(message.getOption2Count() + 1);
                    message.setResponseCount(message.getResponseCount() + 1);
                }
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        UpdateMessageTask updateMessageTask = new UpdateMessageTask(message);
                        updateMessageTask.execute();
                    }
                });

                PollReply pollReply = new PollReply(message);
                pollReply.execute();
            }

        }
    });

    pollChoice3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (message.getAnswered()) {
                if (message.getScope().equals("private") && (message.getResponseCount() < 1) && message.getVisibility().equals("public")) {
                    showAlert("Not enough people have responded to display answers");
                } else {
                    showAlert("You have already answered this poll");
                }
            } else {
                message.setAnswered(true);
                message.setAnswer("" + 2);
                if ((message.getScope().equals("private") && message.getResponseCount() > 0) || message.getScope().equals("domain")) {
                    message.setOption3Count(message.getOption3Count() + 1);
                    message.setResponseCount(message.getResponseCount() + 1);
                }
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        UpdateMessageTask updateMessageTask = new UpdateMessageTask(message);
                        updateMessageTask.execute();
                    }
                });

                PollReply pollReply = new PollReply(message);
                pollReply.execute();
            }

        }
    });

    pollChoice4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (message.getAnswered()) {
                if (message.getScope().equals("private") && (message.getResponseCount() < 1) && message.getVisibility().equals("public")) {
                    showAlert("Not enough people have responded to display answers");
                } else {
                    showAlert("You have already answered this poll");
                }
            } else {
                message.setAnswered(true);
                message.setAnswer("" + 3);
                if ((message.getScope().equals("private") && message.getResponseCount() > 0) || message.getScope().equals("domain")) {
                    message.setOption4Count(message.getOption4Count() + 1);
                    message.setResponseCount(message.getResponseCount() + 1);
                }
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        UpdateMessageTask updateMessageTask = new UpdateMessageTask(message);
                        updateMessageTask.execute();
                    }
                });

                PollReply pollReply = new PollReply(message);
                pollReply.execute();

            }

        }
    });

    pollChoice5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (message.getAnswered()) {
                if (message.getScope().equals("private") && (message.getResponseCount() < 1) && message.getVisibility().equals("public")) {
                    showAlert("Not enough people have responded to display answers");
                } else {
                    showAlert("You have already answered this poll");
                }
            } else {
                message.setAnswered(true);
                message.setAnswer("" + 4);
                if ((message.getScope().equals("private") && message.getResponseCount() > 0) || message.getScope().equals("domain")) {
                    message.setOption5Count(message.getOption5Count() + 1);
                    message.setResponseCount(message.getResponseCount() + 1);
                }
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        UpdateMessageTask updateMessageTask = new UpdateMessageTask(message);
                        updateMessageTask.execute();
                    }
                });

                PollReply pollReply = new PollReply(message);
                pollReply.execute();
            }

        }
    });

    starWhite1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!message.getAnswered()) {
                message.setAnswered(true);
                message.setAnswer("" + 1);
                if ((message.getScope().equals("private") && message.getResponseCount() > 0) || message.getScope().equals("domain")) {
                    message.setOption1Count(message.getOption1Count() + 1);
                    message.setResponseCount(message.getResponseCount() + 1);
                }
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        UpdateMessageTask updateMessageTask = new UpdateMessageTask(message);
                        updateMessageTask.execute();
                    }
                });

                PollReply pollReply = new PollReply(message);
                pollReply.execute();

            } else {
                if (message.getScope().equals("private") && (message.getResponseCount() < 1) && message.getVisibility().equals("public")) {
                    showAlert("Not enough people have responded to display answers");
                } else {
                    showAlert("You have already answered this poll");
                }
            }

        }
    });

    starWhite2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!message.getAnswered()) {
                message.setAnswered(true);
                message.setAnswer("" + 2);

                if ((message.getScope().equals("private") && message.getResponseCount() > 0) || message.getScope().equals("domain")) {
                    message.setOption2Count(message.getOption2Count() + 1);
                    message.setResponseCount(message.getResponseCount() + 1);
                }
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        UpdateMessageTask updateMessageTask = new UpdateMessageTask(message);
                        updateMessageTask.execute();
                    }
                });

                PollReply pollReply = new PollReply(message);
                pollReply.execute();

            } else {
                if (message.getScope().equals("private") && (message.getResponseCount() < 1) && message.getVisibility().equals("public")) {
                    showAlert("Not enough people have responded to display answers");
                } else {
                    showAlert("You have already answered this poll");
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

This is the ListView i use:

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scrollbarSize="3dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:scrollingCache="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

Comment: can you please post some code ? also check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703390/listview-setonitemclicklistener-not-working-by-adding-button

Comment: post your code  here

Comment: Any Code? Register onClick inside of your ListView Adapter.

Comment: Can you Please show your Code and Logcat Error U r getting??

Comment: Have a look at this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703390/listview-setonitemclicklistener-not-working-by-adding-button?lq=1

Comment: Are U using your CustomAdapter?

Comment: How did you load the listview? Post that code

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431631/onchildclicklistener-not-working-in-expandable-list-view/30431773#30431773

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498226/how-to-perform-update-and-delete-operation-in-listview-item-row-while-click-the/27635198#27635198

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
 android:focusable="false"
```

to the xml of the ListViewItems

edit: example ListViewItem xml wit Button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tree_item_container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:background="@drawable/transparent_withline"
android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:focusable="false">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tree_item_toggle"
        android:layout_width="24dip"
        android:layout_height="24dip"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:src="@drawable/closed"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tree_item_status"
    android:layout_width="24dip"
    android:layout_height="24dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/icon12"/>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tree_item_icocontainer"
        android:layout_width="24dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tree_item_docs"
            android:layout_width="24dip"
            android:layout_height="24dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/has_docs" />
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tree_item_coord"
            android:layout_width="24dip"
            android:layout_height="24dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/has_location" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tree_item_textcontainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you explain what it does to the list view items. Since I want to click on items

Comment: If you add any items with seperate OnClickListener to a ListViewItem, you alwas have the problem, that the first click on the Item is used to set the focus to the ListVieItem and the Click event is handeld. its nessecary to set focusable to false, if you want the first click on a item to be handeld by a Onclick Listener of a subitem like Button or ImageView

Comment: Nevertheless the item will get the focus, you won't have any problems with the general behaviour

Comment: A single listview item is Linear layout containing many items. Di I have to set focausable to the LinearLayout or to the child items

Comment: Edited question with the Listview

Comment: To the upper container of the Item.

Comment: android:focusable="false" i cant find this in your edited answer

Comment: I malformed the code and the upper container was not visible, ist in the upper linearlayout, reckeck the Code

Comment: Then do we need to add setfocusable = false o the listview as I edited in question

Comment: i just added that and cant finf much difference in performance

Comment: not to the listview, but to the main container of the item template